# win10 gdb not in executable format: File format not recognized

Tags: c, cmd, gdb, mingw

I'm a C newbie who recently installed gcc and gdb on windows 10 through MinGW. However, when I tried to debug my program using gdb through win10 cmd I got an error.

Here's what I did on cmd:

```
gcc ./test.c
gdb ./a.exe
```

And I got this:

> not in executable format: File format not recognized

Then I tried to install gdb on bash as well and did the following:

```
gcc ./test.c
gdb ./a.out
```

(gcc through bash would create a.out but would create a.exe through cmd)

This time gdb seems to be able to start the executable file correctly, however when I tried typing in break commands I got another error message:

> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Can anyone help to solve the problem?
PS. I've tried using file  but it didn't work either.
PSS.after using `gcc -g ./test.c` the gdb seems to be working correctly on bash. However the windows one still can't run .exe file.

Comment: By default GCC doesn't add debug information. You need to do it explicitly with the `-g` option, as in `gcc -g test.c`

Comment: Thank you! The gdb seems to be working properly with bash. However windows10 gdb still can run a.exe, maybe it's because gdb does not support .exe files?

Comment: Can you actually *run* the `a.exe` in Windows `cmd.exe` as is?

Comment: Yes I have no problem running it directly.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using WSL and I used "file" command as well but it doesn't seem to work anyway. I also tried `-g` and `-ggdb` flags with gcc before using gdb. Anyone has a solution for the WSL case?

Answer (score 0):

Try gdb a.exe

(whitout "./")

I use gdb like that in Ubuntu and works.